# Not finding named style in Generic.xaml

Tags: wpf, styles, themes, custom-controls, staticresource

I have the following custom control

```
public class MagicButton : Control
{
    static MagicButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MagicButton), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MagicButton)));
    }
}
```

with the following Themes/Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type l:MagicButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type l:MagicButton}">
                <Border />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type l:MagicButton}"
       x:Key="OtherStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type l:MagicButton}">
                <Border />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I use the MagicButton control using the default style, everything works, but when I try to use "OtherStyle"

```
<l:MagicButton Style="{StaticResource OtherStyle}"/>
```

it fails to find the style with the exception "{"Cannot find resource named 'OtherStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive."}"

Yet if I move the OtherStyle to App.xaml it works.

I don't want to put it in App.xaml though, what I want is for my Themes/Generic.xaml file to contain default styles as well as key named styles that people can explicitly opt into using

Comment: check your code, i have test and no thing is wrong.  `<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <local:CustomControl1 Width="100" Height="40"  Style="{StaticResource OtherStyle}" Margin="199.5,54.5,217.5,224.5"/>
    </Grid>`

Comment: The 'Themes/Generic.xaml' lives in the same project as the code trying to use 'OtherStyle'. Why is it I have to explicitly add the ResourceDictionary? It seems to work for the default style without doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there is no code behind for the `generic.xaml` file, we cannot create an instance of it to read the `Style` from it. `CustomControl`s access the `Style`s from it using the `DefaultStyleKey`, as you have shown in your example. Therefore, you cannot access it in other ways.

However, `Application.Resources` is the correct place to define your custom `Style`s for this control, as with all of your other controls. You'd be perfectly happy to define `Style`s for a `Button`, or any other .NET control there, so why not for your own controls too?

---

UPDATE >>>

> It's not an application specific style, its an alternative style for the control that I wanted to keep in the theme/Generic.xml so that any project referencing the theme can also use it.

Yes, but you're trying to reference it outside of `generic.xaml` and you can't... it's not like the `Application.Resources`. What you *can* do is to add a `DependencyProperty` to your control which sets the different `Style`s internally.

Comment: It's not an application specific style, its an alternative style for the control that I wanted to keep in the theme/Generic.xml so that any project referencing the theme can also use it.

Comment: So I'm not able to refer to a named Style in generic.xaml?

But my use case is that I want to make a default style for a custom control (i.e. it needs to go in generic.xaml, because, just like @wforl, my library doesn't have an App.xaml dictionary), and I want this default style to be based on a named style from another library. This doesn't seem so ridiculous to me.

What am I supposed to do, put the default style in a resource dictionary and force all code using my library to explicitly merge that dictionary, every time I need to use the control? It seems ridiculous.